# Windows and Mac on network

Tags: windows, macos, networking, mac, homegroup

Is it possible to have shared folders between mac and windows like Homegroup?

Can you get mac folders/computers to show up in the Homegroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant add a mac to a homegroup, because the computers need to run windows 7. But you can create a **Workgroup**.

> 1. **Create a Workgroup.**  Workgroups do not automatically enable as many features as Homegroups, but you can still achieve the same
>      functionality through manual tweaking. To create a Workgroup:
>
>    - Go to the computer running Windows 7. Click on the "Start Menu," right-click on "Computer" and select "Properties."
>    - Go to the tab labeled "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings" and click "Change Settings."
>    - Go to "Computer Name" and click "Change."
>    - A box should pop up named "Computer Name/Domain Changes." You will see the name of the Workgroup you are a member of or you can create a
>        new one.
> 2. **Add your Mac to the Windows 7 Workgroup.**
>
>    - Go to the "System Preferences" pane and click on "Network."
>    - Click on the "WINS" tab and make sure that the Workgroup name displayed is the same as the one you set up on your computer running
>        Windows 7.
> 3. **To make sure your Mac can share files with Windows, go to "System Preferences" and click on "Sharing."**  
>    Follow the interface
>      to change permissions on the folders that you desire.
> 4. **Connect your Mac directly to your PC.**  
>    If you have several Windows 7 computers on a Homegroup and you need to connect
>      your Mac to only one of them, there is another solution that doesn't
>      involve changing from a Homegroup to a Workgroup.
>
>    - Make sure you're on the Mac's desktop. Click on "Go" on the menu bar at the top of the screen. Select "Connect to Server" and type
>        "smb://computersname" in the dialog box. Replace "computersname" with
>        the name of your Windows computer (following the steps to create the
>        Workgroup on Windows will also tell you your computer name).
>    - When it asks for your username and password, type in your WINDOWS username and password. You should now be connected.

[Tutorial-source](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Mac-to-a-Homegroup)